# What is the vapor pressure when the vapor and some inert gas is in a sealed steel container?

Tags: equilibrium

Suppose that there are two chemical species in a sealed container(1L). X(l) is in phase equilibrium with X(g). The another one is Helium gas, which is 2 atm. If the vapor pressure of X at the given temperature is 0.5atm, what is the partial pressure of X in the sealed container? Should I take helium into account while calculating the pressure of X?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. The partial pressure of helium is 2 atm, and the partial pressure of X is 0.5 atm. Does it mean that the total gas pressure is 2.0 atm. Or is it 2.5 atm ?

Comment: Actually, I was asking the same question as you. And I think the answer is 2.5atm, since the partial pressure of X is 0.5atm.

Answer (score 1):

Vapor pressure of X = the partial pressure of X at equilibrium conditions.

The total pressure has to be considered only in context as it very slightly increases vapor pressure of X by slightly increasing the chemical potential of the liquid. (You need more energy to add some volume of liquid to a system with higher pressure.)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer! Now I understand that vapor pressure is the partial pressure that the volatile one has. Did I understand well? Also,  Can I have some more explanation about chemical potential increase? I don’t understand it very well.